# Regex to match city and state in address

Tags: regex

I am trying to create an expression to match the city and state names in addresses such as

```
100 Hall of Justice
1701 Farnam St.
Omaha
Nebraska
68183  United States

3208 Sheridan Ct.
Lincoln
Nebraska
68506

3710 S 192nd St
Omaha
Nebraska
68130  United States

IL Court of Appeals 2nd District
55 Symphony Way
Elgin
Illinois
60120  United States
```

As you can see, the city and state names don't always appear at the same location (node) within the address but they are always laid out as a single word each line between the entire address

Is there a ReGEX that I can use in such a scenario to match only the city and state names irrespective of where they appear within the address?

Comment: Did you try anything? What is regex flavor?

Comment: Hi Anubhava - I am not sure about the regex flavor. I am very new to regex but there are some of the other expressions that I am using

.+(?=\s+[\(]Phone[\)])
^.*
\d+\s\w+\s\w.+

I am using these with WinAutomation software for extracting data from webpages

I am trying `\w+` and `\w.+` but it is matching every word and sentence within the address respectively, I cannot seem to make it match just the city and state

Comment: Try this regex in `MULTILINE` mode: `^([\w-]+)\n([\w-]+)`

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't working. Also I just checked to see that WinAuto uses the .NET flavour of Regex. Does that change anything

Comment: [It works here](https://regex101.com/r/fEALOK/6)

Answer (score 1):

In most simple case the following regex pattern will give the expected *city and state names*:

```
(\w+)\n(\w+)\n\d+(\s+United States)?\n?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/U50ZbJ/3

`(\w+)\n(\w+)` - two capturing groups which will match a *city* and a *state* respectively

Answer (score 0):

Based on @RomanPerekhrest's answer, now it will match two (or more) words in both city name and state name.

`([a-zA-Z ]+)\n([a-zA-Z ]+)\n\d+(\s+United States)?\n?$`